# How to assign a key to "Select All by Trait"? It is not in list

Tags: customization, shortcut

I'm trying to assign a key to "Select All by Trait" (mesh edit mode, "select" menu) but it is not listed in Keymap. Is it possible?

I want to popup this menu on some key, same as Shift+G popups "Select Similar" menu.
Currently I added it to "Q" (Quick Favorites). It's OK generally, but I wonder if it is possible to assign separate key for such unlisted key.

I'm using blender 2.83 and 2.9

Comment: so your question is how to assign another shortcut than Q to a function that has no default shortcut at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the preferences, keymaps, navigate to *"3D view/Mesh/Mesh (global)"*.

Use the *"Add New"* button and set the keymap like so:

[image]

Enter *"wm.call_menu"*, set the key you want and assign the menu name *"VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_by_trait"*.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I think it could be improved by showing how you find the name for a menu or command so it can be applied to other things as well. Where did `VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_select_by_trait` come from? I'd like to make a hotkey for `mesh -> cleanup` as well. Also, is it possible to fire an action directly without the menu? So a hotkey just always does the "select non-manifold" action without showing the "select by trait" menu?